# How to loop data from a data base and post in a form

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get data from a database and display them in a form(which i have done), but i want to post that data individually and get their details.

How do i go about it?

thanks in advance.

**Edited**

Code sample

```
<?php

    $query = query("select * from dtable");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="url">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $rows['user_id']; ?>"><label><?php echo $rows['user_name']; ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="amount">
    </form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

in intend posting this data to the database either with ajax or with normal php which please help.

Comment: could you please provide more information and code examples?

Comment: Share your try, without code its hard to help ?

Comment: @Starbody Are you using Laravel?

Comment: yes am using laravel but no success so am trying it out in normal php.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
public function index()
{       
    $rows = \DB::table('dtable')->get();

    return view('yourview', compact('rows'));
}
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="url">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    @foreach($rows as $row)
        <label>{{ $row->user_name }}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="users[{{ $loop->index }}][user]" value="{{ $row->user_id }}">        
        <input type="text" name="users[{{ $loop->index }}][amount]">
    @endforeach    

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

After submitting the form you can get array of users

```
request()->users;
```

Comment: but how do i get each data for each user for instance id 1 and his in data

Comment: You mean, get specific user data after the form submission?

Comment: i don't have enough reputations to do that

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you want to print a value from a table in an input form. If it's the case this may work for you:

```
<?php $row = "SELECT * FROM table";
$rowQ = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row); ?>

<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $rowQ['column'] ?>">
```

I hope i've helped you